# Blob-поле из Oracle Database записать в файл (C++)

Tags: c++, oracle, файлы, blob

Приведите пожалуйста пример, как записать в файл данные из Blob-поля базы данных Oracle на С++ с использованием вот этой библиотеки (OCILIB) https://vrogier.github.io/ocilib/. Подключиться к БД и сделать выборку обычных данных у меня получилось, но вот с записью данных проблема.

Answer (score 1):

Делается это так:

```
    Environment::Initialize();
    Connection con(L"db", L"user", L"passw");

    std::wcout << L"SERVER VERSION:\n";
    std::wcout << con.GetServerVersion() << std::endl;

    Statement st(con);
    st.Execute(L"select vf.filebody from sm.ver_files vf where vf.filename=\'padeg.dll\'");

    Resultset rs = st.GetResultset();
    while (rs.Next())
    {
        ocilib::Blob blob = rs.Get<Blob>(1);

        big_uint size = blob.GetLength();
        outf.open("padeg.dll", std::ios::out | std::ios::binary);

        if (outf.is_open())
        {
            //outf.write((const char*)&rw[0], rw.size());
            outf.write((const char*)&blob.Read(size)[0], size);

            std::wcout << L"Данные записаны!" << std::endl;
        }
        outf.close();
    }

    con.Close();
```